# Combining similar records and calculating in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

What I am trying to do is hopefully pretty simple:

I have a table that looks like this :

| Geography | Participants |
| --- | --- |
| 01 Brooklyn | 5 |
| 03 Brooklyn | 6 |
| 06 Manhattan | 2 |
| 09 Manhattan | 7 |

What I'd like to do is group by what I know are larger groups here (Brooklyn and Manhattan) and create new counts that would look like this:

| Geography | Participants |
| --- | --- |
| Brooklyn | 11 |
| Manhattan | 9 |

I could create a temporary view/table and operate off of that after using a "LIKE %X%" construction, but I'd like to skip that step. Is there a way to do this or do I have to use a temporary table?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: The table design in wrong. It's combining two fields into a single column, which you should pretty much NEVER do. Fix that broken design (because it really is _broken_) and suddenly this problem becomes easy.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the part of the geography starting on the fourth character, you can use:

```
select substr(geography, 4) as geography, sum(participants) as participants
from t
group by substr(geography, 4);
```

If you don't want to repeat this code, then define a view:

```
create view v_t as
    select substr(geography, 4) as geography, sum(participants) as participants
    from t
    group by substr(geography, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd extract the city's name using [`substring_index`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index), and then group by it and sum the participants:

```sql
SELECT   SUBSTRING_INDEX(geography, ' ', -1), SUM(participants)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(geography, ' ', -1)
```